# How to use tidyr in R to separate a string column into multiple other columns

Tags: r, tidyr

So I am using tidyr in R and I am trying to separate the data in the `'pub_author'` column (attached below) into 3 individual columns: `'website_title'`, `'year'`, and `'author'`. I tried using the *separate()* function doing `separate('pub_author',c('website_title','year', 'author'),'-')`, but since R reads each `'-'` individually it only returns the first three words. Does anyone know how to group the words for title and author so that they will appear in the appropriate column or any other method?

[image: pub author column]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `separate`, we can pass regex lookarounds.  In this case, it would be to match `-` that precedes a 4 digit or a `-` that succeeds a 4 digit

```
library(tidyr)
separate(df1, pub_author, into = c('website_title','year', 'author'), 
     "-(?=\\d{4})|(?<=\\d{4})-")
#        website_title year        author
#1       nfl-draft-geek 2018 justin-miller
#2                  cbs 2019   pete-prisco
#3            sb-nation 2020     dan-kadar
#4    football-fan-spot 2019 steven-lourie
#5             fanspeak 2018       william
#6 acme-packing-company 2020  shawn-wagner
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(pub_author = c("nfl-draft-geek-2018-justin-miller", 
"cbs-2019-pete-prisco", "sb-nation-2020-dan-kadar", 
  "football-fan-spot-2019-steven-lourie", 
"fanspeak-2018-william", "acme-packing-company-2020-shawn-wagner"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun  that worked! In the same vein, how would I separate a column with the following data: 9Shaq LawsonDE | Clemson into 5 columns: number, first name, last name, position and school?

Comment: @GeorgeCoumantaros Based on the comments, perhaps `extract(df, pub_author, into = c('number', 'first name', 'last name', 'position', 'school'), "^(\\d+)(\\w+)\\s+([A-Z][a-z]+)([A-Z]{2})\\s+\\|\\s+(\\w+)")`

Comment: it partially worked but many of the rows are missing values. The rows that worked are perfect, but the rest of them return NA

Comment: @GeorgeCoumantaros could be that some of the rows have a different pattern.  regex is based on matching patterns

Comment: @GeorgeCoumantaros it is better to post as a new question with all the patterns.  thanks

Comment: yes they have different patterns. I posted a new question with a picture of more rows a couple of mins ago. It's only my second post so if you look at my posts you can see it - sorry I'm very new to both stackoverflow and Rstudio you've been tremendous :)

Comment: @GeorgeCoumantaros i would request to use `dput` when posting a question because others cannot copy from images and you could also escape from potential downvotes :=)